# passing arrays from the view to the controller cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

Here is a part of my view(a javascript method that is executed on a button click):

```
function assign()
{
    var links_list1 = [];
    var links1 = document.getElementById('moderatorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links1) {
        if(typeof links1[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list1.push(links1[a].innerHTML);} var str1 =links_list1.toString();
    var moderators = str1.split(',');

    var links_list2 = [];
    var links2 = document.getElementById('editorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links2) {
        if(typeof links2[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list2.push(links2[a].innerHTML);} var str2 =links_list2.toString();
    var editors = str2.split(',');

    var links_list3 = [];
    var links3 = document.getElementById('jEditorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links3) {
        if(typeof links3[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list3.push(links3[a].innerHTML);} var str3 =links_list3.toString();
    var jEditors = str3.split(',');             
}
```

Here is the controller method i need to call using the 3 arrays from the javascript(moderators, editors,jEditors):

```
  function insertPos($moderators,$editors,$jEditors){
        $account = new Account();
        $account->insertPos($moderators,$editors,$jEditors);
    }
```

I need to know how to execute the controller method insertPos($moderators,$editors,$jEditors) using the 3 arrays in the javascript method...

I used this to send the arrays in the javascript like you told me:

```
$.post('http://localhost/cakephp/Accounts/insertPos', {
            data: {
                'moderators': moderators,
                'editors': editors,
                'jEditors': jEditors
            }
        });
```

and in the controller i try to access my arrays like this:

```
public function insertPos() {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)){
        print_r($this->request->data);
        $moderators = $this->request->data['moderators'];
        $editors = $this->request->data['editors'];
        $jEditors = $this->request->data['jEditors'];
        $account = new Account();
        $account->assignPos($moderators,$editors,$jEditors);
        }
    }
```

the part inside the `if(!empty($this->request->data))` is never executed so that means the arrays have not been sent to the controller.... where is the problem?

thank you....

Comment: What have you found and tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access a controller class directly. This is not how CakePHP works. You have to go through the dispatch process. Please read: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/a-typical-cakephp-request.html

That said, the way you would POST to a CakePHP url is thusly:

```
// POST to the AccountsController's insertPos method
$.post('/accounts/insertPos');
```

To pass data, pass it in the `data` option as specified with jQuery, prefixed with 'data', like `data[moderators]` so it ends up in Cake's data variable.

```
$.post('/accounts/insertPos', {
  data: {
    'data[moderators]': moderators,
    'data[editors]': editors,
    'data[jEditors]': jEditors
  }
});
```

The data will now end up in `$this->request->data` in Cake.

Looking at your `insertPost()` method, though, you are passing them simply as parameters, so instead you would write your ajax like so

```
// POST is unnecessary here, since you aren't POSTing data
$.get('/accounts/insertPos/'+moderators+'/'+editors+'/'+jEditors);
```

You will probably need to [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your JavaScript arrays and use [`json_decode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in your `inserPos` method to convert them to PHP objects, since you can't just pass arrays from JavaScript to PHP.

Comment: i want to use post for security reasons....
I am trying to pass these 3 arrays to the controller for 2 days but nothing is working, I am new at this please can anyone help me..
i need to send this 3 arrays from the view to the controller using POST and i also want to know how to access these arrays in the controller....

Comment: @karimgoda I gave you instructions on how to use POST... I added an example to make it more clear. Your Cake method doesn't make use of it, currently, and you'll need to rework it to use `$this->request->data;` instead.

Comment: If it's not getting sent, then something else is happening. Do you have the Security component on? Is it blackholing? Are you using firebug+firephp to debug the response?

Answer (score 0):

don't use array notation in data parameter; just use keys like this:

```
$.post('/accounts/insertPos', {
  data: {
    'moderators': moderators,
    'editors': editors,
    'jEditors': jEditors
  }
});
```

and in your controller access it as `$this->request->data[key]` not `$this->request->data->data[key]`

in the view replace your assign function with the following:

```
var moderators, editors, jEditors;

function assign()
{
    var links_list1 = [];
    var links1 = document.getElementById('moderatorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links1) {
        if(typeof links1[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list1.push(links1[a].innerHTML);} var str1 =links_list1.toString();
    moderators = str1.split(',');

    var links_list2 = [];
    var links2 = document.getElementById('editorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links2) {
        if(typeof links2[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list2.push(links2[a].innerHTML);} var str2 =links_list2.toString();
    editors = str2.split(',');

    var links_list3 = [];
    var links3 = document.getElementById('jEditorUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var a in links3) {
        if(typeof links3[a] == undefined) continue;
        links_list3.push(links3[a].innerHTML);} var str3 =links_list3.toString();
    jEditors = str3.split(',');             
}
```

Good luck

Comment: i have modified the post and did like you said but it's not working can you please take a look on the new one and tell me whats wrong

Comment: And in the controller key names should be quoted like this $this->request->data['moderators'] ...

Comment: i modified the code as you said and still doesnt work ?? please check the post again and tell me whats wrong...
thank you very much...

Comment: The problem is in you js code my friend; define your three variables (moderators, editors, jEditors) as global variables (you can put it just after the <script> tag outside any function definition; and in you assign function just remove the var keyword that precedes these variables and it should work..